# SOAP API Connection through proxy with authentication [407 - Proxy Authentication required]

Tags: soap-api, java

I am following the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login.htm) to connect to SOAP API through a proxy.

```
String proxyUsername = "";
String proxyPassword = "";
String username = "";
String password = "";
String endpoint = "https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/37.0";
String proxyHost = "";
int proxyPort = 0;

System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxyHost);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", Integer.toString(proxyPort));
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", proxyHost);
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", Integer.toString(proxyPort));
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
    @Override
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
    {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(proxyUsername, proxyPassword.toCharArray());
    }
});
ConnectorConfig partnerConfig = new ConnectorConfig();
partnerConfig.setUsername(username);
partnerConfig.setPassword(password);
partnerConfig.setAuthEndpoint(endpoint);
partnerConfig.setProxy(proxyHost, proxyPort);
partnerConfig.setProxyUsername(proxyUsername);
partnerConfig.setProxyPassword(proxyPassword);
PartnerConnection partner = new PartnerConnection(partnerConfig);
```

This has thrown:

> com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Failed to send request to
>   https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/37.0  at
>   com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:121)
>     at
>   com.sforce.soap.partner.PartnerConnection.login(PartnerConnection.java:770)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy
>   returns "HTTP/1.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required"  at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sforce.ws.transport.JdkHttpTransport.connectRaw(JdkHttpTransport.java:136)
>     at
>   com.sforce.ws.transport.JdkHttpTransport.connectLocal(JdkHttpTransport.java:100)
>     at
>   com.sforce.ws.transport.JdkHttpTransport.connectLocal(JdkHttpTransport.java:95)
>     at
>   com.sforce.ws.transport.JdkHttpTransport.connect(JdkHttpTransport.java:91)
>     at
>   com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:95)

I debugged the [JdkHttpTransport](https://github.com/forcedotcom/wsc/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sforce/ws/transport/JdkHttpTransport.java) class on Salesforce and it seems to set the proxy but this throws such an exception. I am able to connect through the Rest API though. The soap trace clearly states that it is setting the properties:

> WSC: Creating a new connection to
>   https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/37.0 Proxy = HTTP @
>   /x.x.x.x:portname username username

Has anyone found a solution to this issue?

Comment: Are you doing anything to your either the ConnectorConfig or PartnerConnection object before your connection.login(String username, String password) call? Can you provide a small snippet of your code?

Comment: @robbyLeeW This is the exact code (replica of documentation). Config's manual login is false and therefore username and password is set on the config. The other option mentioned by you also throws the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite messy as [force-wsc](https://github.com/forcedotcom/wsc) is supposed to handle the authenticated proxy but unfortunately it doesn't. Much worse fact is that dataloader - a similar tool for Apex written in Java works with proxy while wsc is riddled with issues and bugs for proxies. A workaround would be to incorporate a class similar to [HttpClientTransport](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/blob/5fd2ef7316da4cb137ded6fe81d708ac156ec408/src/main/java/com/salesforce/dataloader/client/HttpClientTransport.java) from the dataloader repository and add this line if proxy is enabled:

```
partnerConfig.setTransport(HttpClientTransport.class);
```

This should be handling authenticated proxy. However, the need is authenticated proxy for all the API connections (SOAP, Bulk, Metadata, etc.) but this covers only for SOAP. The bulk connection is not equipped with authenticated proxy as it uses *`HttpURLConnection`* class. I verified this fact with the dataloader.

For Bulk connection, there isn't much of a choice than to rewrite the BulkConnection class. Extend the class and overwrite the `doHttpGet()` method. Recommended way is to use Apache's `HttpClient` libraries instead of the `HttpURLConnection` class. I haven't analyzed the same solution for Metadata connection yet.

It is appalling that a library that is widely used is broken with respect to a feature for so many years.

Answer (score 0):

Try ensuring that your firewall has all of the Salesforce IPs whitelisted: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003652&type=1

Another thing to try is to try the proxy url and host without your login credentials.  Another user had this issue 2 years ago, and the connector class seemed to "lose" the headers for the request [Partner API proxy authentication doesn't work](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/62950/partner-api-proxy-authentication-doesnt-work)

Comment: Firewall is off. Debugging looks like the headers are lost. Similar issue:
https://github.com/forcedotcom/wsc/issues/87

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something similar previously in [Cannot login into Salesforce with Java using Proxy Server](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/172027/102).

In that case they needed to first configure the JVM to use the Proxy before attempting the callout.

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxyHost);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", proxyPort);
```

Comment: Tried this one and still doesn't work.